# How to fix: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory in RedHat 7

Tags: rhel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, make, openssl

I have RedHat Enterprise Linux Server 7, and I downloaded the linux kernel version 4.12.10 which I am trying to compile but when I execute the following command:

```
make modules
```

I get the following error:

```
scripts/sign-file.c:25:30: fatal error: openssl/opensslv.h: No such file or directory
```

Does anyone have an idea to fix this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must install the OpenSSL development files (package `openssl-devel`)